# SAS: avoid printing log in RSUBMIT

Tags: sas

I am using `RSUBMIT` to send several parallel tasks in SAS. Every time I do it, it writes a long text on the log window. Something like:

```
NOTE: Remote signon to TASK1 commencing...
NOTE: FIPS validated AES encryption ....
NOTE: Copyright (c) 2016 ....
NOTE: SAS (r) Proprietary Software ...
NOTE: This session is executing on....

NOTE: Analytical products:
....
....
```

And much more. There is so much "useless" text that makes the log unuseful if I want to print something to check the process of the program I'm working with. Is there a way to prevent all this ouput to be printed in the log, but at the same time print any %PUT that is executed inside the session?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `option nonote;` to turn off notes - that might not eliminate everything though.  But it should help with some of it, at least.  You might need it in both the main and the rsubmitted session.

Answer (score 0):

Check some of the the options on the SIGNON command for more control over the logging. https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.3/connref/p0brzkmxqg483hn163ek01h4mf6e.htm

There are options on the SIGNON command to direct where the LOG and OUTPUT is written when using NOSIGNONWAIT option.

> LOG=KEEP | PURGE | file-specification OUTPUT=KEEP | PURGE |
> file-specification Used only when NOSIGNONWAIT is in effect,
> these options direct the SAS log or the SAS output that is generated
> by the current server session to the backing store or to a file
> specification. A backing store is a SAS utility file that is written
> to disk in the client SAS Work library.

There are options on the SIGNON command to control whether to use Synchronous and Asynchronous SIGNONs. With Asynchronous you can use RGET to time when to retrieve the log.

> Difference between Synchronous and Asynchronous SIGNONs A sign-on is
> executed either synchronously or asynchronously.
>
> synchronous Client session control is not regained until after the
> sign-on has completed. Synchronous processing is the default
> processing mode.
>
> asynchronous Client session control is regained immediately after the
> client issues the SIGNON statement. Subsequent programs can execute in
> the client session and in the server sessions while a sign-on is in
> progress.
>
> Synchronous sign-ons display results and output in the client session.
> If the SIGNON is asynchronous, you can use the RGET and RDISPLAY
> commands and statements and the LOG= and OUTPUT= options to retrieve
> and view the results.